# Why are PhD salaries so low?

Tags: phd, salary, early-career

In many European countries, PhD salaries are incredibly low if compared with industry salaries. In my field, computer science, a young programmer can gain in one in one year what a PhD student gains during all the PhD.  Which are the practical reasons of this?

Some possibilities:

- Money: university have not enough money to pay higher salaries to PhD students. I don't think this is the cause of the low PhD salaries, as given a budget for a project, the PhD students are hired in function of the budget.
- PhD is not considered a job. This, in my opinion, is wrong. PhD actually is a full time job, that requires skills that in many cases (for instance in computer science) will be highly paid in the industry. Projects faced during the PhD are often more complex than homologous industrial projects. The real fact is that a PhD student often (but not always) doesn't produce revenues; but this is true also for professors, for people who take care of the cleaning of the university, and for all the staff of a university, that receive a higher salary then PhDs.
- PhD students are the weakest group of the academia. Nobody, when salaries are decided, says "PhDs should gain more!", because, when salaries are decided, actually they don't have any voice.

Comment: Supply and demand?

Comment: I don't know the situation in Europe, but in the US it's definitely "money".

Comment: @AndyPutman is it, though? I am sure Caltech can get enough funding to pay competitive salaries to its PhD students, but since they will get them anyway, they can pay crap, and hire a load more of them.

Comment: Regarding #3, Stockholm University recently declared that the first salary for PhD students was indeed too low and raised it 70%, and other universities in Sweden did the same. Sometimes, there is someone looking after us!

Comment: There are plenty of people employed at universities who make less than a graduate student in a technical field (graduate students in the humanities may be the first that come to mind, but you really should look around beyond them as well -say, the department assistents). My stipend was enough to live on and save some. And I got a degree out of it with a clear path to higher earnings.

Comment: You should really discuss a location here, as in many places in Europe PhD student salaries are actually quite ok - and I certainly know no place where "a young programmer can gain in one in one year what a PhD student gains during all the PhD". In most places where PhD salaries are low (say, Italy), regular salaries are also bad.

Comment: Who do you expect to pay for their work, and why do you expect that those people would pay more than they have to in order to receive the same services?

Comment: I don't think you understand university budgets very well if you think that universities (even wealthy ones) could easily dramatically increase their graduate student stipends.  It would require a huge amount of money.  And in the hard sciences and engineering (which seem from your other questions to be your main interests), graduate student stipends are mostly paid for out of grant money, so universities have even less control over them.

Comment: Because professors make so little.

Comment: this is one of the reason I decided to work in the industries after my Master Degree

Comment: @StrongBad: There are a lot more graduate students than professors.  For instance, at my current institution (Notre Dame), there are 1610 PhD students and 885 tenure-stream faculty.  Giving all of the graduate students say a $20,000 raise would cost an enormous amount of money (and lots of them are paid through grants, which are definitely a shrinking source of money).  And lots of places have an even more dramatic graduate student to faculty member ratio.

Comment: @AndyPutman my point was giving PhD students a 20k raise would mean they would make more than post docs. Giving a post doc a 20k raise means they would make about the same as assistant professors.

Comment: The question really needs more focus, as you are asking for a comparison of apples, oranges and even bananas here. **There is no thing like a typical PhD salary in Europe, it depends a lot  on the country and discipline** we are talking about.

Comment: For instance, in Germany, a doctoral researcher in engineering typically gets [TVL-E13](http://oeffentlicher-dienst.info/c/t/rechner/tv-l/west?id=tv-l-2016i&matrix=1), which is almost 44 k€ in the first year and raises above 51 k€ in the third year. This is still below industry average, but not significantly. On the other hand, in the sciences, you typically end up with 1/2 E13 position, in the humanities sometimes even just 1/4 – it _is_ a question of supply and demand.

Comment: Personally, I just thought it was a great deal that I didn't have to **pay** for my PhD.

Comment: Are you including tuition in your perception of the total?  In the US, that can be a lot.

Comment: @AndyPutman, your argument about the budget of a university is not justifiable: if someone doesn't have enough money to hire many people, he/she has two options: (1) hire fewer people that he/she can afford to pay according to the candidates' skill-levels, or (2) still hire many people but pay them less. The second option is viable in high-supply-low-demand scenario, but you are still exploiting the needy people here.

Comment: How much do you think they should be paid?

Comment: Also the close is awful. There's a question on the site about why all academic salaries are too low, that's not too broad, but if you ask about why a subset of academic salaries is too low, then it becomes too broad? Come on, mods.

Comment: I can only speak for mathematics, but a lot of the comments above seem to presume that certain aspects/skillsets/roles of PhD students are more-or-less universal across disciplines and countries which is, in my view **not the case**. In my variant of mathematics, PhD students are primarily **students**, being trained. Whether they should get proper and more substantial remuneration for their *work* as *teaching assistants* is another matter

Comment: @Superbest IMO, that's an argument for closing the _other question_, as much as for reopening this one...

Comment: This is the question (http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/16293/why-is-college-tuition-high-but-academic-salaries-low/16302#16302) @Superbest may be referring to. I don't understand how one question is broader than the other either.

Comment: @john Yup, I deleted my comment since I decided to write an answer (with that link), and, well...

Comment: @YemonChoi, the point is to understand the reason for different treatments to two fairly similar questions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43010/discussion-on-question-by-ulderique-demoitre-why-are-phd-salaries-so-low).

Comment: @WBT: Depends, again, a lot on the **actual** country, but in most European countries (including the relatively well-paying Germany, Austria, Sweden/Norway/Finland, Switzerland) there is no tuition.

Comment: And in some EU countries, you don't have a wage at all, or you have just a scholarship. So poor wages are still better than no wages. // So I could only agree with you, that PhDs are not understood like workers, but like students. At least in the Czech Republic. That's why only about 30 % of Czech PhDes complete their program in the assigned period of time. From my perspective most of them drop their carer because of work, they have to find to cover their expenses and then they realize, they have a good job so why suffer in Ph.D. and have no free time? Program so they drop it.

Answer (score 16):

They aren't that low. For example, here in Finland:

- a typical salary for a PhD student: 2400–3000 e/month
- a typical salary in the industry for someone who just got their MSc degree: 3500 e/month.

Comment: Finnish PhD stipends put French ones to shame. My data point: 1600 gross (1350 take-home which is taxed later in the year) in one of the most expensive cities in the world.  But I know that we are already lucky compared to other European countries...

Comment: @lafemmecosmique sure. In the Czech Republic, the average salary of a Ph.D. would be 435 e/month, while the average salary is almost 1800 e/M. I can see France's average salary is about 2587 e/m.

Answer (score 14):

PhD-students are students, advanced students but students none the less. It is a classic form of vocational education: learning on the job. It is a form of long practicum, and they get a stipent or a "wage" that fits that position. When they finish, they will get a diploma.

Comment: No, this depends a lot on the local system. In Germany, they are called "doctoral researchers" and DFG insists on this term because they are _not_ students. You need a Master's degree to start your PhD and are officially employed at your university according to that degree (with the respective rights and duties). In Austria, the situation is similar.

Comment: @Daniel ...and yet it's common practice to give students the same contract as a postdoc but with only 75% paid hours (or even 66% and occasionally 50%), on the rationale that the other 25% is for their thesis.

Comment: I feel like this beats around the bush. PhD students work an incredibly high-skilled and demanding job and yet are paid much less than they could get in industry. Whether they are technically students or not does not serious address why this discrepancy exists.

Comment: I really disagree with this thinking. Not all the bells and whistles and fancy paper in the world will change the fact that you are taking an adult in their late 20s, who has a degree and qualifications enough for a pretty good career, and busying him full time for 4-10 years, where his main activity is supposed to be research work, and the small hope of being supported by his parents is destroyed in that he is required to relocate. It's one of those things that walks like a duck, quacks like a duck, and wears a big hat saying "goose" and gets inexplicably half the salary it should.

Comment: @MaartenBuis, do you think if the universities (say in the USA) really start charging fees from their Ph.D. students, there will be so many Ph.D. students?! How many of them would actually be fees-paying Ph.D. students?!

Comment: PhD students work hard, but they are *not* yet fully capable researchers.I don't mind that PhD students take that much longer and make too many mistakes I need to correct; that is part of the learning experience. Having PhD students is part of my teaching job, which I enjoy greatly, but it is costing me time not saving me time. This attitude safes a lot of frustration with me *and* the students: What they are doing does not have to be perfect yet. We will make it perfect, and in the process they will learn more about doing research.

Comment: People in the industry also need years of practice to become fully capable professionals. Junior professionals are far from being independent, but they are still treated as professionals. If someone has published a first-author paper (or equivalent), they are obviously capable of doing research and no longer students.

Comment: Yes, and only in special cases, where there is a great shortage of people with specific skills, are they paid like full professionals. The normal case is that they are paid less, just as with PhD-students. My economics training ( a long time ago) tells me that if people are paid more than their productivity, then the market is in disequilibrium.

Comment: The market is also in disequilibrium when a PhD student publishing several first-author papers per year is paid like an undergraduate intern. The academia is a bureaucracy, where individual productivity has very little effect on compensation.

Comment: The fact that they published a paper does not proof they did so efficiently. Again I am not saying PhD students are bad, only that they have a lot to learn.

Answer (score 12):

PhD students are paid in more then just the money they get directly. They're also able to take highly technical classes, have direct access to some of the best minds in their field, get sent to international conferences, and gain free vocational research training. All of this is normally covered by their university.

You could argue that PhDs help produce research and that benefits their school. But learning how to do research is the entire point of the PhD and they benefit from publications as much as their university does, if not more.

The fact that you can get paid enough money to live comfortably on top of all of the these benefits is amazing and, the the best of my knowledge, not found anywhere else. How many places do you know who would pay you to sit around and train for 3-7 years knowing that you will leave as soon as you're decently competent?

Comment: Which is almost certainly more fun than building CRUD app backends at foocorp, even if less lucrative.

Comment: I know right? I don't understand what the OP is complaining about -- no one does a PhD for the money.

Comment: I like this answer. Getting a PhD doesn't seem to pay much, but if you think of it in terms of most of your salary is going immediately back into paying for tuition (which is typically covered), suddenly the amount of money PhD students receive seems to be much larger.

Comment: @Kevin Tuition fees are rarely that high in Europe.

Answer (score 4):

The disparity in pay in the computer science industry specifically, compared to PhD research, is because there is currently a **massive deficit** of experienced software developers in the computer science industry.

The higher industry salaries are designed to get qualified candidates and keep them there, to deliver on projects. No developer means no work means no money.

I would wager that PhD students do not play musical chairs. In the industry, turnover is a very real problem.

Comment: plus one for pointing out that compsci is a bit of an outlier compared to most fields.

Comment: Do you have numbers for pay in comp sci in some countries?

Comment: @Kimball only from the US, but I believe Master's in CS would be around $75K to $80K right now as a starting salary.

Answer (score 3):

Mainly because it's not *just* a job. Although I do see it gaining recognition as one: we do produce a lot of an institution's research. You are still in training (even in postdocs), this isn't just hierarchy, it's degree-inflation.

A PhD is also an **Education**, an investment in your future, arguably increasing your future job prospects:

- work opportunities abroad (conference, postdocs)
- greater independence in your work than a less qualified job
- job security (e.g., tenure-track)
- potentially higher salary post-PhD (depending on job market)

Our stipend in comparably lower in Aus/NZ than EU but it usually also includes a tuition fees waiver. The contribution of international PhD students at our university is also recognised by only charging domestic fees during the first 3 years, even if they aren't eligible for a stipend.

Think of a PhD on a stipend like a job with lower pay but some perks: a huge emphasis on training, free education, conference opportunities, tax-free income.

Comment: My main piece of advice to those considering a PhD course is do it while you're early in your career. Some people do fantastic things coming back after experience in industry or education but it's logistically easier to go straight into it from study. A stipend is more income than most undergraduates live on and it's fairly comfortable when that's your standard of living (e.g., renting a flat, public transport). If you've become used to a high income (e.g., mortgaged your own house, had children, or taken personal loans), PhD study (even part-time) can be a lot more financially stressful.

Answer (score 1):

If we compare academia and industry, I think there is a keyword for the big salary differences, responsibility.

I once asked a PhD student, why he did not want to take a better paid industry job and he answered he had nightmares about firemen-work. Like his code would make a big mess in production and he had to clean up. It really depends on what kind of work day you want. A delayed research paper affects nobody but your self, but a bug in a code can delay a whole plant.

And as an MSc in industry, your work has a purpose to make higher values for the company so there is definitely more weights on the shoulders for an industry engineer compared to a PhD student.